# how to split a string with regular expression in vbscript

Tags: regex, vbscript, asp-classic

I have to split a string in vbscript with below token

```
_[any digit].archiveRT
```

For Example    **_1.archiveRT**

Plase tell me how can I split such in vbscript

Comment: If the pattern is similar, then you can simply use `Split` to split the string on dot

Comment: actually I have to fetch string before this last token.

Answer (score 1):

While you surely could implement your own SplitOnRe() function (modelled e.g. on Perl's split), the dirty/risky trick of replacing the regexp's matches with a unique/not possible in data marker and Split() on this may be less effort for (nearly) the same gain. In Code:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "\d+"
>> For Each s In Array("x12y", "ab0cd", "a99999999b")
>>     WScript.Echo Join(Split(r.Replace(s,"<>"), "<>"), "|")
>> Next
>>
x|y
ab|cd
a|b
>>
```

(The idea is (c) dm_4ever; see his [contribution](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=49790) to the discussion on Split/RegExp)

Answer (score 0):

You said you have to fetch the string *before* this last token? So do you have a string like this?

```
foofoofoo_1.archiveRT
```

In that case, if the first part of your string is guaranteed to **not** contain an underscore, you could just split on `_`.

```
s = Split("foofoofoo_1.archiveRT", "_")

' s(0) is now "foofoofoo"
```

If there may be underscores in your string (prior to your "token"), you could just trim off the last `Len("_1.archiveRT")` characters.

```
s = Left(s, Len(s) - Len("_1.archiveRT"))

' or...

s = Left(s, Len(s) - 12)
```